# Warning: ‘buffer-local-value’ is an obsolete generalized variable in Emacs 29

Tags: warning, buffer-local

In Emacs 29.0.60,

`(setf (buffer-local-value 'foo (current-buffer)) 42)`

produces the warning above.

What's the recommended way of changing a buffer-local variable in another buffer? (the above is an MWE).

Comment: See [bug#26624](https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2017-09/msg00891.html)  for the context.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: You might better reply to/ask in that thread as linked to by NickD, but I guess we're back to setting the variable within a `with-current-buffer` then...